# Configuration of pcl with cmake

Tags: ros, build-from-source, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to pcl and cmake..

So here am stuck in installation of pcl in linux_ubuntun14.04 ..

I had downloaded the pcl_master.zip from github. Besides I had also installed pcl through terminal sudo apt-get pcllibaries....

While trying an example it showing the following error..

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" (requested
  version 1.2) with any of the following names:
    PCLConfig.cmake
    pcl-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "PCL" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "PCL_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "PCL" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/iamlantern/Desktop/pcl_install/pcl-pcl-
1.7.2/examples/Proj/hdc/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Thanks for your patience and happy to follow your great suggestions....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199799/configuration-of-pcl-with-cmake/) by [lantern](https://answers.ros.org/users/21171/lantern/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several ways to install PCL, the first solution is to install the last release using ROS repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-ros
```

You could also [install PCL with the PPA for Ubuntu](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) but in fact this is how PCL is installed when you install PCL-ROS package.

If you need the bleeding edge version of PCL you have to compile it yourself using [PCL trunk](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl). You want to compile PCL when you need features not included in releases/PPA (CUDA, surface module etc.) or you use something that has been improved/fixed into PCL repository but not in a release yet.

When installed through ROS/PPA, the CMake files are located in

```
/usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfig.cmake
/usr/share/pcl-1.7/PCLConfigVersion.cmake
```

If you build and install (default CMake prefix) PCL from source the cmake files are located in

```
/usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake
/usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfigVersion.cmake
```

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2014-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4